# Fake Deleting a file in Git

Tags: git, delete-file

I committed some files ages ago and pushed them to GitHub. They weren't meant to be committed and I was wondering if there was a way to fake delete them in a commit? As a last resort I could physically delete them, commit and restore but it would be great if there was a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`--cached` option](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Removing-Files) to `git rm` to remove the files from your repository, but not your working copy:

```
git rm --cached file.txt
```

The files will remain on your filesystem, but they'll be removed from Github when you push the commit. If you're working with other people, then this **will** remove the files from their repository the next time they `git pull`.

Beware, though; the files will still be accessible from the git history, so if the files contain sensitive information like passwords you'll have to [follow Github's instructions on purging sensitive information instead](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data).

Comment: Thanks for the extremely informative answer, that seems to have done the trick. Now to find out why unmodified files keep appearing when I attempt to commit something.